# How to use env in Sequelize migration config file?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, sequelize.js, nestjs

I use NestJS.
At the root of the project I created a file `.sequelizerc`:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('src/database', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('src/database', 'migrations'),
  config: path.resolve('src/database', 'config.js'),
};
```

As well as the configuration file in `src/database/config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_HOST),
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  },
  production: {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.DB_HOST),
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  },
};
```

When running the migration (`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`) using env I get the error: `Access denied for user ''@'localhost' <using password: NO>`.
The reason for the error is that it is not possible to read values from env.

How can I use env in given config?

I tried adding `require('dotenv').config()` to the `config.js`.
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem was that I used `.development.env` and `.production.env`.

I added `require('dotenv').config({ path: '.production.env' })` to `config.js`.